# Google Closure compiler not compressing string values?

Tags: javascript, compression, minify, google-closure-compiler, yui-compressor

Having something like this:

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    $.fn.demo = function (options) {

        var active = "active";
        var section = ".bb-demo";

        $(section).addClass(active);
        $(section).addClass(active);
        $(section).addClass(active);
        $(section).addClass(active);

    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

[Closure Simple mode](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) results in **200 bytes**:

```
(function(a,b,c,d){a.fn.demo=function(b){a(".bb-demo").addClass("active");a(".bb-demo").addClass("active");a(".bb-demo").addClass("active");a(".bb-demo").addClass("active")}})(jQuery,window,document);
```

While [YUI compressor](http://ganquan.info/yui/) results in **169 bytes**:

```
(function(c,b,a,d){c.fn.demo=function(e){var g="active";var f=".bb-demo";c(f).addClass(g);c(f).addClass(g);c(f).addClass(g);c(f).addClass(g)}})(jQuery,window,document);
```

Isn't there a way to compress those string variables in Closure as well?
why isn't it doing it? 
Is it because of better results in terms of performance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Closure compiler from duplicating string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060799/prevent-closure-compiler-from-duplicating-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered is Closure Compiler FAQ. https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#closure-compiler-inlined-all-my-strings-which-made-my-code-size-bigger-why-did-it-do-that

> Closure Compiler assumes that you are using gzip compression. If you
>   do not, you should. Configuring your server to gzip your code is one
>   of the most effective and easiest optimizations that you can possibly
>   do. The gzip algorithm works by trying to alias sequences of bytes in
>   an optimal way. Aliasing strings manually almost always makes the
>   compressed code size bigger, because it subverts gzip's own algorithm
>   for aliasing. So Closure Compiler will (almost) always inline your
>   strings when it can, because that will make your compressed code
>   smaller.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the FAQs in github!